# Nonlinear system of equations. Find a and b

Tags: real-analysis, systems-of-equations

After solving some integrals I received the two following equations to solve for a and b:
$$\frac{1}{3}=\frac{-e^{-b}+e^{-a}}{(b-a)^2}$$
$$\frac{\text{arcsinh}{(2)}+2\sqrt{5}}{4}=\frac{1}{b-a}\Bigg[\frac{\ln\big(\sqrt{e^{-2x}+1}+1\big)}{2}-\frac{\ln\big(\sqrt{e^{-2x}+1}-1\big)}{2}-\sqrt{e^{-2x}+1}\Bigg]_a^b$$
With these two equations I do not know where to start algebraically and I do not have the technology to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? You can input your query in Mathematica as you are unlikely to come across a solution by hand.

Comment: There are two identical logarithms ! Typo, I presume.

Comment: What is $x$? If is just a parameter, then you could simply solve the second equation for b - a. Then replace the denominator in the first equation with the expression for b-a. Then solve the second equation for b and replace b in the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Admitting that there is no typo, you have to find $a$ and $b$ such thet
$$f(a,b)=\frac{e^{-a}-e^{-b}}{(b-a)^2}-\frac{1}{3}=0$$
$$g(a,b)=\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-2 a}}-\sqrt{1+e^{-2 b}}}{b-a}-\frac{1}{4} \left(\sinh
   ^{-1}(2)+2 \sqrt{5}\right)=0$$ So, consider that you want to minimize
$$\Phi(a,b)=\big[f(a,b)\big]^2+\big[g(a,b)\big]^2$$

Make a contour plot first such as [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%28-1%2F3+%2B+%28E%5E%28-a%29+-+E%5E%28-b%29%29%2F%28-a+%2B+b%29%5E2%29%5E2+%2B+++%28%28Sqrt%5B1+%2B+E%5E%28-2*a%29%5D+-+Sqrt%5B1+%2B+E%5E%28-2*b%29%5D%29%2F%28-a+%2B+b%29+%2B+++++%28-2*Sqrt%5B5%5D+-+ArcSinh%5B2%5D%29%2F4%29%5E2%3D%3D1%2F1000%2C+%7Ba%2C+-2.5%2C-1.5%7D%2C+%7Bb%2C+2%2C4%7D%5D) and zoom more and more reducing the ranges. This gives you a very good idea of the solution. When this is done, use Newton-Raphson method (even with numerical derivatives and get
$$a=-2.11535\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=2.85505$$ Checking for these values, $f(a,b)=-2.43 \times 10^{-13}$ and  $g(a,b)=-4.44 \times 10^{-16}$ .

Comment: Sorry there was a typo however, disregarding the typo, can I use a similar method?

Comment: @hwood87. I knew that there was a typo (see my comment almost one hour ago). For sure you can; I wanted to give you a methodology for this kind of problems. With two varaibles, it is a piece of cake. Cheers :-)